# Form submission/validation in a route with page redirect - Laravel

Tags: laravel

In my blade file

```
<form id="" 
      class="form-horizontal" 
      accept-charset="UTF-8" 
      action="/apply/post/{{$content->vacancy->Id}}" 
      method="POST">
```

And my `routes.php`:

```
Route::get('/apply/post/{ref}', function($ref) {

// 1. Define some rules and validate...
    $rules =  array('forename' => array('required'), 'email' => array('required'), 'surname' => array('required'), 'address1' => array('required') );

$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, array('required' => 'The :attribute is required.') );

if( $validator->fails() ) {
    $messages = $validator->messages();
    return Redirect::to("http://example.co.uk/apply/{$ref}")->withInput()->withErrors($messages);
 } else {
    // do stuff with Input::all()
 }
}
```

No matter what I try for `Redirect::to()`, i.e. `Redirect::back()` Upon form submission, I end up getting redirected back to `http://example.co.uk/apply/post/234` which leads me to an undefined route and an error page.

If the user fails validation I really want them redirected back to `http://example.co.uk/apply/234` with the errors/messages displayed. This way they can re-try entering the correct information with the form eventually getting submitted to `http://example.co.uk/apply/post/234` say.

Don't ask, I inherited the code and my Laravel is beginner, but is this possible using the framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You POST to the route from your form

```
method="POST"
```

But your route is defined as GET

```
 Route::get('/apply/post/{ref}', function($ref) {
```

change it to POST

```
 Route::post('/apply/post/{ref}', function($ref) {
```

Comment: Thanks. I try with `Route::post()` its now fighting me with: `The HTTP status code "0" is not valid.`

Comment: Edit: It now works with `Redirect::to("http://example.co.uk/apply/{$ref}")->withInput()->withErrors($messages);`